# Artin Algebra 7.4

Tags: abstract-algebra

(7.4) Proposition: The maximal ideals of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are the principal ideals generated by the linear polynomials $x-a$. The ideal $M_a$ generated by
$x - a$ is the kernel of the substitution homomorphism $S_a: \mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ which sends
$f(x) \to f(a)$. **Thus there is a bijective correspondence between maximal ideals $M_a$
and complex numbers $a$.**

I am confused about the bolded part, how exactly is there a bijection? (i.e which result was used?). Specifically, I want to know if the correspondance between $M_a$ and $a$ follows directly from the previous statements of the proposition. (i.e do I need to prove the bijection manually)

Comment: To each complex number $a$ corresponds the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=(X-a)\subset \mathbf C[X]$ and vice-versa.

Comment: Ok, does it follow directly from the previous statements of the proposition or no?

Comment: I guess $C$ means $\mathbb C$?  The ideals $(x-a)$ are always maximal, but you need the field to be algebraically closed in order to conclude that *all* maximal ideals have that form.  For example, $(x^2+1)$ is maximal in $\mathbb R[x]$, and is not of that form.

Comment: Yes, it does result from the previous statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition says that $m$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ if and only if there exists $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $m=(x-a).$ The bijective map is defined as follows: send each maximal ideal to the constant term of the (monic degree 1) polynomial which generates it.